# Can i get Idea? How to write PHP code if anyone of the selected Categories of products presents in the cart the shipping method is Admin selected one

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, category-selector

If anyone of the selected Categories of products presents in the cart the shipping method is admin selected one. now  my shipping methods like user selections, like

1)DHL
2)FEDEX
3)INDIA POST

If the anyone of the selected Categories of products presents in the cart, **no matter other categories of products also included** in the cart. if my selected Categories of products presents in the cart the shipping method is **INDIA POST**

How can i solve this issue? can i get an idea about how to write Manual PHP Condition?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly I don't think you can do this from a shipping cart rule. You need a third party extension (something like webshopapps product matrix) and then use an attribute to control which shipping methods are used for different products

Comment: Non of the magento default rule options used to hide shipping method. You need to do custom code for this.

Comment: @jscar Is any other option available instead of webshopapps product matrix?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya could you pls share any idea how to hit this?

Comment: @zus there may be other commercial extensions but I don't know of them.

Comment: I post answer, you can used that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement below code in any one custom extension.

Add this code in your config.xml file of your extension.

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method_available>Vendor_Extension_Block_Method</onepage_shipping_method_available>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
<global>
```

Create file `Vendor/Extension/Block/Method.php` which remove your shipping method based on condition:

```
<?php
class Vendor_Extension_Block_Method extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        $yourtempvar = true;
        // BASED ON CONDITION SET VALUE true false in $yourtempvar variable

        $rates = parent::getShippingRates();
        if (array_key_exists('your_shipping_method_code', $rates) && $yourtempvar !== false) {
            unset($rates['your_shipping_method_code']);
        }

        return $rates;
    }
}
```

Comment: bro, Thank You. could you pls explain briefly

Comment: Already explain in brief bro. you need to implement the code.

Comment: I am adding XML code to Webshopapps_Matrixrate Module : config.xml : https://codepaste.net/2pn6bn

Comment: and app\code\local\Gta\Extension\Block\Method.php  : https://codepaste.net/f6qzhq

Comment: May i know what is the "your_shipping_method_code"

Comment: "your_shipping_method_code" is the shipping method code which you want hide based on condition.

Comment: could you pls help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/215022/57334